# Blurry image on mobile, not on desktop. Solution?

Tags: android, windows, image

Sorry if this is a duplicate, but I couldn't find any questions here or through Google that matched my needs.

I am working on a small image (167px x 98px) and I noticed that it came up clearly on my desktop, but on the mobile version of the site it looked blurry (not pixelated though). It's still legible but noticeably hazy.

After some research, I realized that it was related to the pixel density. My monitors only have a density of 102 PPI while my phone has 554 PPI. So, I thought if I raised the PPI while maintaining the desired dimensions, I should be able to increase the quality of the image while maintaining the size. I bumped the PPI up to 550 and the result was essentially the same as the original 72 PPI image I started with.

Is there anything else I can do to improve the quality?

More info: This is an image that must be uploaded to Netsuite to be used as the site's logo, so there is no coding that would interfere. Image is PNG-24 format as it has a transparent background. I tried regular RGB and raising the image to 32-bit RGB. I also tried increasing the PPI to 700 in both color formats. While the 32-bit version made the image look better, it was still blurry.

Tested in: Firefox and Chrome mobile on a LG G5. Tested in Edge, Firefox, Chrome and IE on desktop. Running Windows 10, Samsung LED monitors that are 21.5 inches in 1920 x 1080 resolution.

Comment: 'I thought if I raised the PPI while maintaining the desired dimensions,' How would you rise the ppi of a monitor?

Comment: I'm not referring to raising the PPI of the monitor. I'm talking about raising the PPI of the image. In Photoshop, when you go to adjust the size of an image, you have an option to change the resolution of the photo. The resolution defaults to pixels/inch or PPI.

Comment: Impossible. Images have no PPI. Images have only WxH in pixels. So they have a number of pixels. Images have no dimensions. Only pixels.

Comment: Images certainly have PPI. If they did not, we would not be able to convert pixel size to other units of measurement like inches or centimeters. When you print an image that is x amount of pixels by x amount of pixels, you can still take a ruler to it and measure the image. Height and width are also types of dimensions. So, yes, images do have dimensions. I expressed those dimensions in pixels in the question. If you're not trying to answer the question, by all means, do not comment.

Comment: Images files have no ppi. They have only pixels. There are no inches. If you print an image on a piece of paper then dimensions like inches are involved. Also when you display an image on a monitor then the image is displayed in a certain area with more or less inches. Its up to you on how many inches you want to display your image. You can change ppi for displaying on paper and monitor.  But you cannot change ppi for an image as the image itself has no inches and hence no ppi. Images have only pixels. You edited your post but you are still talking about ppi. You should know better now.

Comment: I've not edited my post since you've commented.

Comment: YOU edited your comment.

Comment: Also, what you're saying is not helpful at all. If you want to argue that the image itself doesn't have PPI itself, but I can still adjust how it displays, you are literally talking about the same thing I'm referring to while attempting to mince words and avoid the question. I am changing the resolution of the image in PPI. That's the unit I'm adjusting. That's changing how it is displayed. I am doing that to the image file itself.